# Discontinuous complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to compute the integral $$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+\infty}\frac{x^{s}}{s(s-1)}ds $$  for $ x \geq 1$ and $ c > 0$. I know that it should be $ \sim x $ and that if $ s-1 $ wouldn't appear at the denominator, it would be $ 1 $. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\Theta}$ is the *Heaviside Step function*. With
$\ds{x \geq 1}$ and $\ds{c > 0}$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{{1 \over 2\pi\ic}
\int_{c -\infty\ic}^{c + \infty\ic}{x^{s} \over s\pars{s - 1}}\,\dd s}
\\[3mm] = &\
\Theta\pars{c - 1}{1 \over 2\pi\ic}\,\braces{2\pi\ic\lim_{s \to 1}
\bracks{\pars{s - 1}\,{x^{s} \over s\pars{s - 1}}}} + {1 \over 2\pi\ic}\,\braces{2\pi\ic\lim_{s \to 0}
\bracks{s\,{x^{s} \over s\pars{s - 1}}}}
\\[3mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{\Theta\pars{c - 1}x - 1} =
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{-1} & \mbox{if} & \ds{c < 1}
\\[2mm]
\ds{x - 1} & \mbox{if} & \ds{c > 1}
\end{array}\right.\,,\qquad\qquad
x \geq 1\,,\quad c > 0
\end{align}

Comment: @Raizen Glad to help. Thanks.